# Service Fabric solution will not build

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric

I'm getting the following. Does anybody know what that's about

> C:***\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.2\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(385,5):
>   error MSB4062: The "VerifyVersionCompatibility" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly
>   C:***\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.2\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.BuildTasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:***\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.2\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.BuildTasks.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Comment: Can you verify if the version of the package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild` is the same in the sfproj file and the nuget package referenced by the service projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you do not have the Service Fabric SDK\Tools installed on your VS, or the version you have is not compatible with your project version. This generally happens when we install new version of SF SDK.

Check if you have it installed, and if the version you have is compatible.
- To check the version installed, you can navigate to Visual Studio Extensions and look for Service Fabric  Tools

- If you have SF installed, the easiest way I found to fix this is creating a new SF project, compare the configurations from .sfproj to the old one and fix the paths.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the file "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.BuildTasks.dll" exists in the "packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.2\build\" folder.

I had a similar error message, but mine is through building a Service Fabric solution in VSTS. The issue was that the BuildTasks.dll was not uploaded to the VSTS.